# Lisp redefining functions

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Can someone help understand what is happenning here?

```
(DEFUN G(L)(+(CAR L)(CADR L)))
(SETQ H`F)(SET H `G)
```

I want to know what happends when I evaluate (F` (2 3 4 5 6 ))

I've written it in my lisp interpreter but I get the following error:

```
Undefined function F
```

Comment: I assume you mean single quote (`'`) not back-tick (`) in your post?

Comment: @mbratch judging from the other formatting and style (e.g., spacing, capitalization, and the use of `set`), I expect (hope!) that this might have been copied from an older source, perhaps that typeset quotes in code with backquotes in text.  In this case, fortunately, it doesn't make a difference, since it's just quoted symbols.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor good point. I see several Unicode single quotes kicking around posts as well from that same process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Common Lisp has a namespace for values and another namespace for functions.

```
CL-USER 49 > (DEFUN G(L)(+(CAR L)(CADR L)))
G

CL-USER 50 > (SETQ H 'F)
F

CL-USER 51 > (SET H 'G)
G

CL-USER 52 > F
G

CL-USER 53 > (symbol-value 'F)
G

CL-USER 54 > (symbol-function 'f)

Error: Undefined function F in form (SYMBOL-FUNCTION F).
```

All you did was setting the value of `F`, but not the function `F`.